# Typeahead on reactive Forms - typeahead doesnt show up

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, angular-reactive-forms, ngx-bootstrap

Since the doc on typeahead with reactive forms is very 'limited' I cant tell if this is a bug or the problem sits in front of the pc.^^
Issue:
I want to make a async http call everytime my form changed. So far this happens and I get everytime a new result when my form updates (it is what i want). BUT The typeahead with the array doesn't appear.

```
<input type="text"
               class="form-control"
               required minlength="3"
               name="name"
               placeholder="Search for people..."
               formControlName="name"
               [(ngModel)]="name"
               typeaheadOptionField="name"
               [typeaheadOptionsInScrollableView]="2"
               [typeahead]="dataSource | async"
               [typeaheadOptionsLimit]="100"
               [typeaheadScrollable]="true"
               [typeaheadAsync]="true"
               (typeaheadLoading)="changeTypeaheadLoading($event)">
```

And the component:

```
   this.dataSource = this.form.valueChanges.pipe(
      debounceTime(500),
      switchMap((form) => {
        return this.service.getstats(form).map((result:someTypedArr[]) => {
           return result;
        });
      })
    );
  }
```

Note: I have the async pipe in the Observable binding - that means - I subscribe to it in the html template.

Comment: Did you try narrowing down the problem? Is it the async loading of the data or the "reactive way" of declaring forms as stated in the title?

Comment: when I type `console.log` before the result return i get everytime the expected array shown when something changed on the form - so i guess the typeahead maybe needs another way of subscription - I was hoping for some typeAhead experts here^^

Comment: can't see much wrong with your observable definition

Comment: Maybe create a plnkr/jsfiddle to encourage people fiddling around with the problem. As Fan Cheung already stated, the code looks ok and the rest would be guesswork.

Comment: found out the solution 1 min ago, lol^^

Comment: @creep-story What was the solution, I think I am stack on the same situation here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some trial and error I figured how to show me the results in the typeAhead i created an EventEmitter property:

```
public clanEmitter: EventEmitter<ClansByClantagType[]> = new EventEmitter<ClansByClantagType[]>();
```

and emitted the result of the subscription:

```
this.form.valueChanges.pipe(
  debounceTime(500),
  switchMap((form) => {
    return this.service.getstats(form).map((result:someTypedArr[]) => {
       return result;
    });
  })
).subscribe(result => {
  this.clanEmitter.emit(result);
});
```

The eventEmitter was in the html included like so:

```
<input type="text"
           class="form-control"
           required minlength="3"
           name="name"
           placeholder="Search for people..."
           formControlName="name"
           [(ngModel)]="name"
           typeaheadOptionField="name"
           [typeahead]="clanEmitter"
           [typeaheadScrollable]="true"
           [typeaheadAsync]="true"
           (typeaheadLoading)="changeTypeaheadLoading($event)">
```

Although I solved it now, would be cool if someone could tell me **WHY** this actually worked^^

Comment: As the [ngx-bootstrap documentation](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/typeahead#api-reference) states, the `[typeahead]` property can be an "observable". By using the [AsyncPipe](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe) you immediately subscribed to that observable and passed on the return value from `getstats(form)` as typehahead data source. `getstats()` probably returned an empty array for `form === ""`. As there was no data, no typeahead popup was shown.